# mysql replication deadlock slave stopped

Tags: mysql, replication, deadlock

I've a master and slave and got the slave stopped with the following error log in slave. I want to fix this and **get the two servers on synch and get going again.**

```
111128 8:42:24 [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master 'repl@masterIP:3306', replication started in log 'mysql-bin.000006' at position 169

111128 15:46:50 [ERROR] Slave: Query caused different errors on master and slave. Error on master: 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction' (1213), Error on slave: 'no error' (0). Default database: 'Dbase'. Query: 'insert into archieved(eid,at,rtime,scode) select id,at,avg(rtime),scode from tstatus where date(at)="2011-10-29" group by id', Error_code: 0 111128 15:46:50 [ERROR] Error running query, slave SQL thread aborted. Fix the problem, and restart the slave SQL thread with "SLAVE START". We stopped at log 'mysql-bin.000006' position 1277768
```

I'm not sure how to do the following:

```
try restarting transaction' (1213)
```

Note: I've got the following in slave, IO running and sql stopped. I just want **to resynch and also avoid this in future.**

```
 Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
            Master_Host: masterIp
            Master_User: repl
            Master_Port: 3306
          Connect_Retry: 60
        Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000006
    Read_Master_Log_Pos: 3156089
         Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000002
          Relay_Log_Pos: 1277834
  Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000006
       Slave_IO_Running: Yes
      Slave_SQL_Running: No
        Replicate_Do_DB:
```

Thanks.

Comment: I Think you need to check your master server status over the time.  Errors like this (deadlocks) need to be checked without the replication. I think that in time you get this error, your server was heavy loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to restart the transaction from your application, mysql has already forgotten about it.

When Mysql encounters a dead lock it will pick one "winner" and let that thread continue, the other thread will do rollback, release it's locks and get the "try to restart the transaction"-error.

Your application should try to detect this and try the same query again. Hopefully you won't get the deadlock again.

As to your slave, I haven't seen this error before and it is a bit confusing, I would think that the query on the master that failed would never be written to the bin log and therefor there could never be a "different error on the master and slave"

Either way. To fix this you need to run

```
SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1; START SLAVE;
```

This will *ignore* the first statement in the bin log and then restart the server. Whatever that statement was it will not be run on the slave, so you have to manually make sure the tables are the same on the master and slave afterwards.

Good luck.

Comment: please see Note added in my question. I still don't get the data resynched however, should I run the SKIP_COUNTER now?

Comment: `sql running: no` means that the replication has stopped on an error. You need to fix the error and restart the slave. You can either just `start slave` but unless the statement that broke replication can run it's just going to stop again. Somewhere in `show slave status` there is a row called `last replication error` or something. Investigate why this statement worked on the master and not on the slave, that is how you can avoid this in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  it is synching.